# What are the differences between these two circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging, dc

As a beginner in electronics, I'm seeking clarification on the differences between two circuits. Could someone please explain the differences? Based on analysis, both circuits output an overall voltage of 11.1V. The left circuit consists of pairs of 3.7V batteries connected in series, while the right circuit features series connections of 3 3.7V batteries connected in parallel. What is the specific purpose of each configuration? Which configuration provides a higher current output?

[image]

Comment: What have you considered when analysing this? Have you considered the resistance of the connecting wires with the internal resistance of each cell? What conclusions would you draw? Showing some effort is a good start on here.

Comment: Regarding the connecting wires, I cannot determine their resistance, but it's likely negligible. Similarly, I don't have datasheets for the cells to know their internal resistance, so I'm disregarding them as well. I haven't drawn any conclusions yet; if I had, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. This is precisely what I'm trying to ascertain. I've already made efforts by researching and simulating the two configurations on Multisim. The image you see is from the simulation tool, indicating my dedication to finding an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To first order, there is no difference in the two circuits. They can both hold the same amount of energy, deliver the same power, and 'look' the same to a charger or load connected to the terminals.

The difference comes in the supporting circuits and hardware, and the way they fail.

For instance, for balance charging, the left hand circuit could use one balancer, whereas the right hand circuit needs two. If the left circuit is built from three individual series modules, it needs a heavier wire to connect the modules together than it does to connect the cells.

I'll leave it to you to work out what sort of lower performance or source of danger is the result of any individual wire going open circuit, or cell going open or short. This general procedure is called FEA, Failure Effects Analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation